# How to merge two classes into single unit?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, list

```
List<ReportDataInfo> Lrdi = new List<ReportDataInfo>();
ReportDataInfo rdi = new ReportDataInfo();
ReportDataInfo RdiMerge=new ReportDataInfo();
string[] AccountTypeCodeCustomArray = 
AccountCodeTypeCustom.Split(",".ToCharArray());
string[] SubTypeCodeCustomArray = 
SubAccountTypeCodeCustom.Split(",".ToCharArray());
string[] AccountCodeCustomArray = AccountCodeCustom.Split(",".ToCharArray());
for (int i = 0; i < AccountCodeTypeCustom.Length; i++)
{
    rdi = ExportDataToCSV.GetLedgerReportData(Globals.GetInt( 
     AccountTypeCodeCustomArray[i],0),Globals.GetInt( 
     SubTypeCodeCustomArray[i],0),Globals.GetInt( AccountCodeCustomArray[i],0), 
     this.CurrentSessionInfo.Company.CompanyCode, 
     this.CurrentSessionInfo.FinancialYear.StartDate, 
      this.CurrentSessionInfo.FinancialYear.EndDate);
   // Lrdi.Add(rdi);
    RdiMerge.Rows.Concat(rdi.Rows);                        
    //RdiMerge.ReportHeading = rdi.ReportHeading;
    //RdiMerge.Rows = rdi.Rows;
}

CurrentSessionInfo.ReportData = RdiMerge;
```

This is the things i have tried before

Now my question is
i want merge returned ***ReportDataInfo*** from ***ExportDataToCSV.GetLedgerReportData();***

I am stuck here whatever values returned from ***ExportDataToCSV.GetLedgerReportData();***
I want to merge into single ***ReportDataInfo*** and then pass to  ***CurrentSessionInfo.ReportData = RdiMerge;***

ReportDataInfolooks like

```
[Serializable]
public class ReportDataInfo
{
    public string ReportHeading { get; set; }
    public List<ReportColumnInfo> Rows { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `List<T>` has an `AddRange()` method. Have you tried that?

Comment: no @EladLachmi example would be great for me

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx - The MSDN page about `AddRange` of `List<T>`. The idea is the `AddRange` takes an `IEnumerable<T>` and appends it to the end of the list. That is what you want, right? Or did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it simply use Automapper

AutoMapper is an object-to-object mapper, which allows you to solve issues with mapping of the same properties in one object of one type to another object of another type. For example, mapping a heavy entity Customer object to the CustomerDTO could be done with AutoMapper automatically

Comment: hello jayraj could you give me example?